# Symfony 2: PHP templates autoloading

Tags: templates, symfony

Can anyone help me with a Symfony 2 (I'm newby with it).

I just installed framework, created my own bundle and it worked fine till I switched template engine from Twig to PHP.

The steps I did:

- specified `templating: { engines: ['php', 'twig'] }` in *config.yml*
- renamed view file from `hello.html.twig` to `hello.html.php`
- changed twig template code to php's `echo`

Also if inside the action I leave:

```
return $this->render('MyBundle:Default:index.html.php', array('name' => $name));
```

all OK, but when I changes it to:

```
return array('name' => $name);
```

Symfony shows me an error: **Unable to find template "MyBundle:Default:index.html.twig"**

Comment: @elnur yep, the same error page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you use the `@Template()` annotation? From [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html):

> If you are using PHP as a templating system, you need to make it
>   explicit::
>
> /**
>       * @Template(engine="php")
>       */
>     public function showAction($id)
>     {
>         // ...
>     }

So you should add `engine="php"` to the annotation.

Comment: Thanks!! This is axactly what i have looked for!!)) you're amazing ;)